# Is there a way to open/read a database file created by updatedb with python?

Tags: python, linux, locate

I'm just curious if anyone has done this before. I'd like to use the database file generated by updatedb as sort of a "cache" for a searching mechanism, but without having to make any external calls to 'locate'.

Comment: this database format is probably platform-specific and implementation-specific.

Comment: ascobol: Looks like you're at least partly right: "The locate database is not byte order independent.  It is not possible to share the databases between machines with different byte order.  The current locate implementation understands databases in host byte order or network byte order if both architectures use the same integer size."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having a look at this file:

https://github.com/WojciechMula/locatedb

I believe it does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [plocate](https://github.com/Aetf/plocate). It supports the [mlocate db format](https://linux.die.net/man/5/mlocate.db) which is very common. But have a look at the TODO section of the [README.rst](https://github.com/Aetf/plocate/blob/master/README.rst) if it suits your needs.